# Dynamice sql in pl/sql not working in 11g oracle DB

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am getting  this error when i am trying to use dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch to get result of

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
ORA-06512: at line 136
```

Purpose of this code is to get trend of those components of shared pool which have been in top 5 list anytime.
Because the top 5 list varies i have to use list aggregate in pl/sql to get the PIVOT working for me. Purpose of the PIVOT is to transpose the bytes for each of the components of the shared pool into separate columns.

I am able to get this code working in 12c using the dbms_sql.return_result function but somehow not able to get the equivalent working in 11g.

Below is the code i use in 11g and which is **not** working

```
col bytes for 999,999,999,999
col name for a30 trunc

define p_days=&2
define p_inst_num=&1

prompt
prompt

declare
  sql_query clob;
  cols clob;
   l_cursor  NUMBER := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   l_dummy integer;
   l_dummy2 integer;
   l_columns dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   l_value NUMBER;
begin
  select listagg('''' || NAME || ''' as "' || NAME || '"', ',') within group (order by NAME)
  into   cols
from (
with snapids as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ snap_id from dba_hist_snapshot  where instance_number=&&p_inst_num and begin_interval_time >sysdate-&&p_days
)
,rnks as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            dhsg.bytes,
            rank() over (partition by dhsg.snap_id order by dhsg.bytes desc )  rnk
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     pool='shared pool'
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
,toprnk_pools as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ distinct name from rnks  where rnk <6
)
,toprnk_statsonly as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            dhsg.bytes
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si,
            toprnk_pools tp
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     dhsg.name=tp.name
    AND     dhsg.pool='shared pool'
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
SELECT distinct name FROM toprnk_statsonly );

  sql_query :=
  '
with snapids as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ snap_id from dba_hist_snapshot  where instance_number=&&p_inst_num and begin_interval_time >sysdate-&&p_days
)
,rnks as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,''yyyy/mm/dd hh24'') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            dhsg.bytes,
            rank() over (partition by dhsg.snap_id order by dhsg.bytes desc )  rnk
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     pool=''shared pool''
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
,toprnk_pools as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ distinct name from rnks  where rnk <6
)
,toprnk_statsonly as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,''yyyy/mm/dd hh24'') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            round(dhsg.bytes/1024/1024,0) bytes
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si,
            toprnk_pools tp
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     dhsg.name=tp.name
    AND     dhsg.pool=''shared pool''
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
  select * from
  (
      select *
      from toprnk_statsonly
  )
  pivot
  (
      MIN(BYTES) for NAME in ('||cols||'  )
  )';


   dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor, sql_query, dbms_sql.NATIVE);
   dbms_sql.describe_columns(l_cursor, l_dummy, l_columns);
   FOR i IN 1..l_columns.count LOOP
      dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, i, l_columns(i).col_type);
   END LOOP;
   l_dummy := dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch(l_cursor, TRUE); /* this is the reason for the error */
--
--
   FOR i IN 1..l_columns.count LOOP
      dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, i, l_value);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_columns(i).col_name ||' = '||l_value);
   END LOOP;
end;
/
```

I have adapted this code with help from the below link

[Display Dynamic EXECUTE Output Within pl/sql From sqlplus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366426/display-dynamic-execute-output-within-pl-sql-from-sqlplus)

i am getting this error when running it.

[image]

Below is the code i use in 12c and which is working fine.

```
col bytes for 999,999,999,999
col name for a30 trunc

define p_days=&2
define p_inst_num=&1

prompt
prompt Showing  free memory trend
prompt

declare
  sql_query clob;
  cols clob;
   l_cursor  NUMBER := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   l_dummy NUMBER;
   l_columns dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   l_value NUMBER;
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  select listagg('''' || NAME || ''' as "' || NAME || '"', ',') within group (order by NAME)
  into   cols
from (
with snapids as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ snap_id from dba_hist_snapshot  where instance_number=&&p_inst_num and begin_interval_time >sysdate-&&p_days
)
,rnks as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            dhsg.bytes,
            rank() over (partition by dhsg.snap_id order by dhsg.bytes desc )  rnk
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     pool='shared pool'
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
,toprnk_pools as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ distinct name from rnks  where rnk <6
)
,toprnk_statsonly as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            dhsg.bytes
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si,
            toprnk_pools tp
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     dhsg.name=tp.name
    AND     dhsg.pool='shared pool'
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
SELECT distinct name FROM toprnk_statsonly );

  sql_query :=
  '
with snapids as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ snap_id from dba_hist_snapshot  where instance_number=&&p_inst_num and begin_interval_time >sysdate-&&p_days
)
,rnks as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,''yyyy/mm/dd hh24'') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            dhsg.bytes,
            rank() over (partition by dhsg.snap_id order by dhsg.bytes desc )  rnk
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     pool=''shared pool''
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
,toprnk_pools as
(
    select /*+ materialize */ distinct name from rnks  where rnk <6
)
,toprnk_statsonly as
(
    SELECT
            /*+ materialize */
            to_char(dhs.begin_interval_time,''yyyy/mm/dd hh24'') s_hr,
            dhsg.name,
            round(dhsg.bytes/1024/1024,0) bytes
    FROM
            DBA_HIST_SGASTAT dhsg,
            DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT dhs,
            snapids si,
            toprnk_pools tp
    WHERE
            dhs.snap_id=si.snap_id
    AND     dhs.instance_number=&&p_inst_num
    AND     dhsg.snap_id=dhs.snap_id
    AND     dhsg.instance_number=dhs.instance_number
    AND     dhsg.dbid=dhs.dbid
    AND     dhsg.name=tp.name
    AND     dhsg.pool=''shared pool''
    ORDER BY  1 asc
)
  select * from
  (
      select *
      from toprnk_statsonly
  )
  pivot
  (
      MIN(BYTES) for NAME in ('||cols||'  )
  )';

/* 12c working code starts here  */
    open rc for sql_query;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);

/* 12c working code end here  */
end;
/
```

Below is the sample output when working fine.

[image]

I am not familiar with DBMS_SQL at all so not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: It appears your code is generating a SQL statement which won't run. Dynamic SQL is hard to get right. You need to dump your generated statement to screen or file so you can run the statement as a static statement.

Comment: Please just print out the string before submitting it. Thx.